# Programmaticallly moving files in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to simply move files from folder `path1` to folder `path`.

```
import os
import shutil
path1 = '/home/user/Downloads'
file_dir = os.listdir(path1)
fpath = '/home/user/music'
for file in file_dir:
    if file.endswith('.mp3'):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(file_dir,file), os.path.join(fpath, file))
```

... but I get this error

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Comment: The method `listdir()` returns a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path.  [source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm).  Do `file_dir = os.listdir(path1)[0]` perhaps?

Comment: `(os.path.join(file_dir,file)`here you are trying to join a list with a string, check this line again.

Comment: `(os.path.join(file_dir,file)` should be `(os.path.join(path1,file)` I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use `file` as a variable name, it's a builtin in python, consider using `f` instead.

Also notice that in the `shutil.move` line, I've changed your `(os.path.join(file_dir,f)` to `(os.path.join(path1,f)`. `file_dir` is a list, not the name of the directory that you're looking for, that value is stored in your `path1` variable.

Altogether, it looks like this:

```
import os
import shutil
path1 = '/home/user/Downloads'
file_dir = os.listdir(path1)
fpath = '/home/user/music'
for f in file_dir:
    if f.endswith('.mp3'):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(path1,f), os.path.join(fpath, f))
```

Comment: I guess it depends on 2.x vs 3.x with the use of `file`, but for backwards compatibility (who does that?) it should probably be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You have confused your variable purposes from one line to the next.  You've also over-built your file path construction.

You set up `file_dir` as a list of all the files in `path1`.  That works fine through your `for` command, where you iterate through that list.  The `move` method requires two file names, simple strings.  Look at how you construct your file name:

```
os.path.join(file_dir,file)
```

Remember, `file_dir` is a *list* of files in `path1`.  `file` is one of the files in that list.  What are you trying to do here?  Do you perhaps mean to concatenate `path1` with `file`?

**NOTE**: Using pre-defined names as variables is *really* bad practice.  `file` is a pre-defined type.  Instead, use `f` or `local_file`, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully the error message. `file_dir` is list. You can not join it with os.path.join. You probably want to write:

```
shutil.move(os.path.join(path1, f), os.path.join(fpath, f))
```

I suggest to name variables with meaningful names like:

```
file_list = os.listdir(path1)
```

This way you will not join a file list with a path :)